# videorecording issue

Tags: android

I write a program which records video using MediaRecorder. When I press the home button and lauch app from the menu on long press home button camera is not responding, a black screen is shown.
Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

---

> 11-26 11:37:06.779: INFO/DEBUG_TAG(346): onPause executes ...
>   11-26 11:37:06.819: INFO/WindowManager(75): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=0
>   11-26 11:37:06.829: INFO/WindowManager(75): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3 orien=1 layout=18}
>   11-26 11:37:07.209: DEBUG/StatusBar(75): updateResources
>   11-26 11:37:07.219: INFO/DEBUG_TAG(346): surfaceDestroyed executes ...
>   11-26 11:37:08.139: INFO/DEBUG_TAG(346): onStop executes ...
>   11-26 11:37:08.139: INFO/OMXVenc(51): send_command::690 attempt to move to new state 2
>   11-26 11:37:08.139: INFO/OMXVenc(51): process_state_change::2452 Req to Move to Idle: Call venc_stop
>   11-26 11:37:08.149: INFO/OMXVenc(51): process_DL_status::2610 got DL status for VENC_CMD_STOP
>   11-26 11:37:08.149: INFO/OMXVenc(51): process_DL_status::2681 encoder already moves to idle state. call event handler now
>   11-26 11:37:08.159: INFO/OMXVenc(51): send_command::690 attempt to move to new state 1
>   11-26 11:37:08.169: DEBUG/CameraService(51): stopRecording (pid 51)
>   11-26 11:37:09.149: WARN/AudioFlinger(51): AudioRecordThread: buffer overflow
>   11-26 11:37:10.299: INFO/ActivityManager(75): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.motivity.videorecording/.login }
>   11-26 11:37:10.649: DEBUG/dalvikvm(75): GC freed 6246 objects / 305240 bytes in 304ms
>   11-26 11:37:10.659: INFO/WindowManager(75): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=0
>   11-26 11:37:10.669: INFO/WindowManager(75): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=0/0 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3 orien=2 layout=18}
>   11-26 11:37:10.669: INFO/ARMAssembler(75): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00000504_00000000 [ 18 ipp] (37 ins) at [0x278350:0x2783e4] in 305175 ns
>   11-26 11:37:10.699: WARN/WindowManager(75): performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLocked called while in layout
>   11-26 11:37:10.869: DEBUG/StatusBar(75): updateResources
>   11-26 11:37:13.069: DEBUG/dalvikvm(75): GC freed 908 objects / 39000 bytes in 204ms
>   11-26 11:37:13.569: DEBUG/NetworkLocationProvider(75): onCellLocationChanged [131,31183]
>   11-26 11:37:20.340: WARN/ActivityManager(75): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
>   11-26 11:37:20.861: WARN/ActivityManager(75): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43324650 com.motivity.videorecording/.VideoRecording}

Answer (score 0):

Kindly show us Error Logs here. It may possible camera is being used by other application, if its so then re-boot device and check again.
-Thanks